# Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined in Modal popup Bootstrap 5.1

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am facing issue on bootstrap 5.1 modal popup and getting error Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined . I  tried both code on displaying modal popup and still same issue exists. I want to call this modal popup through javascript method only as i have a requirement to display modal popup based on scenarios.

```js
function show() {
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'),{})
    myModal.show();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="show()">
Open modal
</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated, using `javascript` triggered:

More can be found on the documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo

Why are you using two bootstrap `JS` files?
Included the latest version available as well:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {});
const trigg = document.querySelector('#modal-trigger');

function showModal(el){
  el.show();
}

// Event 1:  show after 1 second:
setTimeout(function() {
  showModal(myModal);
  trigg.style.display = 'inline-block';
}, 1000)

// Event 2: show on click:
trigg.addEventListener('click', function(){
  showModal(myModal);
});
```

```css
#modal-trigger {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-trigger">
Open modal
</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you really must mix vanilla JS with jQuery (for whatever reason), you can do the following:

```
const trigg = $('#modal-trigger');

trigg.on('click', function(){
  showModal(myModal);
});
```

Comment: I want to display modal popup in javascript as i have requirement to display popup based on conditions/scenarios

Comment: @user2432361, updated the example using JS, not having any errors shown. Added the line in a reusable function as well.

Comment: Tried the above code still same issue exists

Comment: @user2432361, I updated your example, the issue is that you are using attributes combined, take out this line: ```data-bs-toggle="modal"``` and it will work.

Comment: @user2432361 Didn't this fix it for you?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct. The reason your Popup is not showing is that is not defined.

This happened to me today, I was doing conditional rendering of a modal in React. What was going on exactly is that while I was returning the modal markup I was also calling a function to show it.

The mistake was that I was trying to show the modal while it wasn't returned yet, hence why `document.getElementById('myModal')` was undefined. In order to solve this, I always rendered the modal and I showed it only if a certain condition was true.

I'm sorry I'm so late, and I hope that I can help somebody with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You were close ,

new bootstrap.Modal expect another param.

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {})
```

Comment: Still same issue exists